# Jenkins/maven builds fails due to codehaus repo migration

Tags: maven, jenkins

Jenkins build have started to fail with the error below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException:   
Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for 
artifact 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar': Error getting POM for   
'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils' from the repository: Unable to read 
local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from 
'/usr/share/tomcat5/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-
beanutils/1.9.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-codehaus.org.xml': end tag name 
</body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 7 (position: TEXT seen ...
</address>\n</body>... @9:8) 
commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:pom:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT
```

As per my understanding or the debugging I have done leads me to migration of codehaus repo from http to https as displayed on their main page: https://www.codehaus.org/termination-503.html

Some debug logs:

```
`[DEBUG] Skipping disabled repository codehaus.org
[INFO] artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils: checking for updates from activiti-repo
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol https
[DEBUG] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Connecting to repository: 'activiti-repo' with url: 'https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public'.
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol https
[DEBUG] repository metadata for: 'artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils' could not be found on repository: activiti-repo
[DEBUG]     commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT:runtime (setting version to: 1.9.3-SNAPSHOT from range: [1.4,))
[DEBUG] Skipping disabled repository central
[DEBUG] Skipping disabled repository central
[INFO] snapshot commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from activiti-repo
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol https
[DEBUG] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Connecting to repository: 'activiti-repo' with url: 'https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public'.
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol https
[DEBUG] repository metadata for: 'snapshot commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT' could not be found on repository: activiti-repo`
```

At present I am using maven2 but have tried maven3 and it fails as well. Any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing a similar issue ( maven 2.2 , jdk 1.6, Jenkins and the error above). We need to add mirrors in order to ensure that that requests to codehaus repo are routed to alternative location.

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
           <mirrorOf>codehaus.org,codehaus,codehaus-repository,codehaus-snapshot</mirrorOf>
            <name>remote-repos-mirror</name>
            <url>http://my-nexusorartifactory/remote-repos</url>
            <id>remotes</id>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <name>central</name>
            <url>http://my-nexusorartifactory/artifactory/libs-releases</url>
            <id>central</id>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <mirrorOf>snapshots,snapshot</mirrorOf>
            <name>snapshots</name>
            <url>http://my-nexusorartifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshots</url>
            <id>snapshots</id>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

This repo can be used as an alternative to codehaus: https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/public/

More information: [Codehaus Maven Repository Usage Guide (web.archive.org mirror)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150525235507/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/HAUSMATES/Codehaus+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)